# foreach over DNS host addresses

Tags: c#, foreach, host

I have this code:

```
IPHostEntry host = null;
Socket sock;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry("ip..");

foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7777);
    sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ipe);
    if (sock.Connected)
    {
        sock.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"), ipe);
    }
}
```

This code works ok on localhost, but when I write vps ip, code not working, what's problem?

Comment: What doesn't work? The foreach, connecting, or something else? Do you get any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: foreach not works, Nope i don't get any messages :(

Comment: And what is the exact `Dns.GetHostEntry()` line when it doesn't work?

Comment: If I write Dns.GetHostEntry("xxx.x.x.x"); Not works but when I write Dns.GetHostEntry("subdomain.mysite.com"); Works..

Comment: P.S subdomain.mysite.com is redirect to xxx.x.x.x

Comment: I've tried `Dns.GetHostEntry(string)` with various IP-adresses and domains without being able to recreate your issue. Are you absolutely sure the IP address you put in is correct? Is the DNS server set up correctly for this/these IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your DNS is set up incorrectly and `Dns.GetHostEntry(string)` fails at the second point below. If the DNS server fails to do a reverse lookup it won't return a hostname, so `Dns.GetHostEntry(string)` doesn't know what to look up and will return an empty address list.

From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx

> 1. The method tries to parse the address. If the hostNameOrAddress parameter contains a legal IP string literal, then the first phase succeeds.
> 2. A reverse lookup using the IP address of the IP string literal is attempted to obtain the host name. This result is set as the HostName property.
> 3. The host name from this reverse lookup is used again to obtain all the possible IP addresses associated with the name and set as the AddressList property.